# Convert deep JSON object into Mongo schema

Tags: json, mongodb, meteor

I am trying to file a deep JSON object into a Mongo Collection schema. The object has an interesting shape:

```
{
  data: {
    a: {
      'kjndsgheid': { foo: true, bar: false },
      'weidmeirfi': { foo: true, bar: false },
      'dfnbewetee': { foo: true, bar: false },
      'dbnfryhred': { foo: true, bar: false }
    },
    b: 1
  }
}
```

This has me stumped because `a` is an object whose keys are random IDs - I could store `a` as a blob, however each random keys' properties are fixed and I would like these represented in the schema.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Isn't Mongo schemaless? Where do you define the schema?

Comment: I'm defining the schema with Meteor SimpleSchema. However I don't think my question is specific to that. Mongo won't file the above JSON blob regardless of Meteor. I could be wrong -- I'm a newb on this subject.

Comment: OK, maybe you should tag this question with `Meteor`. Mongo will be happy to store this JSON for you:
`> db.test.find({})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("586441ba40561b849a48b949"), "data" : { "a" : { "kjndsgheid" : { "foo" : true, "bar" : false }, "weidmeirfi" : { "foo" : true, "bar" : false }, "dfnbewetee" : { "foo" : true, "bar" : false }, "dbnfryhred" : { "foo" : true, "bar" : false } }, "b" : 1 } }
> 
`

Comment: Hmm. Okay. Maybe meteor just isn't letting me save it?

Comment: Maybe; I am not that familiar with `meteor`. Hopefully someone with `meteor` expertise will chime in.

Comment: Okay, you're right. It's a Meteor SimpleSchema problem.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema/issues/244

Comment: Shoot - yeah that's the exact problem. Doesn't look implemented yet. Thanks for finding.

Comment: If you want to do some aggregations later you will have some problem if you have a significant amount of records in database with that kinds of data with dynamic keys. For instance, if you want to get all keys that have `foo:true`, you will have to perform this in mapReduce (very slow) as projection with dynamic key is not implemented. see : https://jira.mongodb.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/SERVER-5947

Answer (score 1):

I'd try this, although it involves modifying the schema slightly :

```
ASchema = new SimpleSchema({
  key : {
    type : String,
  },
  foo : {
    type: Boolean,
  },
  bar : {
    type : Boolean,
  }

})

DataSchema = new SimpleSchema({
  a : {
    type : [ASchema],
  },
  b : {
    type: Number,
  },

})

Data = new Mongo.Collection('data')
Data.attachSchema(DataSchema)
```

Inserting will involve modifying your JSON on the go. Alternatively, and if you don't care about validating your a key, you might want to use the Object type instead of the custom ASchema.